# Implement K-nn in matlab with an specific dataset

Tags: matlab, repository, knn

Good night! I'm trying to implement classification by K-nn, without using any toolbox, but right now I'm pretty ignorant using Matlab, so I have no idea what to do. I'm trying to classify the dataset Teaching Assistant Evaluation, from the University of California Machine Learning repository.  Right now, I've just managed to divide my training set, label set and test set and classify them with the toolbox, but without it I'm completely lost.
Can you please help me with an idea of how to start? I've been searching for a template or a base code, but none of them is understandable for me. By advance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is for euclidean distance KNN, you can change the definitions of the distance by your needs:

```
% generate data
dim = 2;
K = 3;
ntest = 10;
ntrain = 100;
nlabels = 3;
traindata = rand(ntrain,dim);
trainlabel = randi(nlabels,[ntrain 1]);
testdata = rand(ntest,dim);
testlabel = zeros(ntest,1);
for ii = 1:ntest
    % compute euclidean distances
    dists = sum(bsxfun(@minus,traindata,testdata(ii,:)).^2,2);
    % take the closest neighbors' label
    [~,idxs] = sort(dists);
    labels = trainlabel(idxs(1:K));
    % majority vote
    testlabel(ii) = mode(labels);
end
% plotting
scatter(traindata(:,1),traindata(:,2),50,trainlabel);
hold on
scatter(testdata(:,1),testdata(:,2),50,testlabel,'filled');
hold off
colormap('jet')
legend('train data','test data')
```

[image]